# Rpart - NA handling

Tags: r, na, rpart

I am struggling with the NA functionality in the Rpart package. I got the following dataframe (code per below)

```
  Outcome VarA VarB
1       1    1    0
2       1    1    1
3       1   NA    1
4       0    0    1
5       0    0    0
6       0   NA    0
```

I am trying to fit a Rpart object that makes a perfect prediction. The logical rule should be that it predicts that:

- If VarA=1, prediction=1
- If VarA=0, prediction=0
- If VarA=NA, then VarB is used (If VarB=0, prediction=0)

However, I am struggling to find the right code to "pass the NA values" for VarA down the tree in the correct manner. I have tried to work with `usesurrogates` and `na.control`, but to no avail... please find me code below.

PS. The rpart works if VarA would read `VarA=c(1,1,2,0,0,2)` but unfortunately this is not a great solution for the larger dataframe that I am working on....

```
library(rpart)
Outcome=c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
VarA=c(1,1,NA,0,0,NA)
VarB=c(0,1,1,1,0,0)
dg=as.data.frame(cbind(Outcome, VarA, VarB))        
dg
fit=rpart(Outcome ~ VarA + VarB, data=dg, method="class",na.action = na.pass,control=rpart.control(usesurrogate=1, minsplit=1, cp=0.001))
fit

newdata=dg
newpred=predict(fit,newdata=newdata,type = "class")
dh=cbind(dg,newpred)
dh
```

Answer (score 1):

I took your code and modified it to use the `NA` handling logic you wanted.

```
library(rpart)
Outcome=c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
VarA=c(1,1,NA,0,0,NA)
VarB=c(0,1,1,1,0,0)
dg=as.data.frame(cbind(Outcome, VarA, VarB))        
dg
```

I changed these lines:

```
dg$VarC <- ifelse(
    is.na(dg$VarA),
    ifelse(df$VarB == 1, 1, 0), dg$VarA)
fit=rpart(Outcome ~ VarC, data=dg, method="class",
   na.action = na.pass,
   control=rpart.control(
       usesurrogate=1, minsplit=1, cp=0.001))
```

The rest is the same:

```
fit

newdata=dg
newpred=predict(fit,newdata=newdata,type = "class")
dh=cbind(dg,newpred)
dh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing VarA automatically with something like this:

```
VarA [is.na(VarA )] <- 2
```

This should replace all NA with 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i understand from your above question is you want to use VarB whenever varA fails:-

```
VarA [is.na(VarA )] <-VarB[is.na(VarA )]
```

but your prediction completely depend on VarA(fit) so make changes in VarA before passing it to rpart.you will get your predicted output.